# How to rollback on micro service when some http requests are successful and some http requests are fail by using jdbcTemplate

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, spring-cloud-stream

I have spring boot projects built on micro service and use KONG as api-gateway. All services are in **Docker container**.

In my situation, I use **serviceA** loop 20 times to request to delete records in **serviceB** by using *jdbcTemplate*. The first 10 requests are successful. So 10 records are deleted from postgresql database in **serviceB**. But the 11th request is error. So I would like to rollback all 10 records that were deleted successfully from database.

My question is that could I rollback in this situation? If it is possible to rollback, how can I do? and which technology should I use? Could I use Spring cloud stream and Kafka in this situation to rollback?

Comment: No you cannot rollback, you can only rollback if everything would be in a single transaction. So you need to compensate for this yourself by, probably, manually restoring the records or don't loop but make the possibility to remove everything in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your supporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use distributed transactions, which is quite heavy approach...

Other then that you can change architecture, which is also not perfect advise.

Going to some real advises.

General question here is, if that is the only, problematic case. If so - that is quite easy - extend your API in the way that allows multi delete in one operation. Please look at Oracle/Scim [API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMDEV/scim.htm#CACCADFH). So changing single group is atomic. Problem starts, when someone with to move user from one group to the other. So maybe you can deal with problematic cases by adding special method - like presented `patch`?

Other then all of that. You can use `command` design pattern and have revert for each operation. That is still tricky since not all reverts are possible, but that highly depends on your case.

### UPDATE

There is something like Saga pattern. For particular operations there is revert operation prepared. And there is manager who knows what went wrong, and which reverts are required. [Here](https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/) is article for that. Sometimes it works, but... reversals are really problematic operations - like sending email. :)